# YDN-DB executeSql didn't work properly on browser

Tags: javascript, ydn-db

I have a stack that using **executeSql** in **ydn-db**. When I use **executeSql** in **ydn-db**, I didn't get properly. Here my snippet.
My **cacheDB** schema is;

```
var p = new promise.Promise();
cacheDb = new ydn.db.Storage(dbName,db_cache_schema);
cacheDb.executeSql("SELECT * FROM category_item WHERE ref_id = '"+categoryId+"' LIMIT   "+ limit + " OFFSET " +offset).then(function(items) {
     p.done(items);
}, function(e) {
     throw e;
});
return p;
```

Error is ***cacheDb.executeSql is not a function***

My current browser is **Firefox 34.0** and OS is **Ubuntu (14.04) 64**

Is that require to do something to use **executeSql**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the library with `sql` module, such as `ydn.db-is-sql.js`, available in [download page](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/downloads.html).